# Substring Between Two Indexes instead of Index, Length

Tags: c#

I was working on a text file importer today, and I got tired of using the normal Substring(startIndex, length) method.  I like to use Fridays to learn new things or think of new ways to do something, so I wrote my own extension that instead takes two indexes because I find that easier to visualize in my head.

I ended up with something like this:

```
public static string SubstringIx(this string value, int startIndex, int endIndex)
{
    if (value == null) throw new ArgumentNullException();
    if (endIndex > value.Length) throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("End index must be less than or equal to the length of the string.");
    if (startIndex < 0 || startIndex > value.Length + 1 ) throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("Start index must be between zero and the length of the string minus one");
    if (startIndex >= endIndex) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Start index must be less then end index");

    var length = endIndex - startIndex;
    return value.Substring(startIndex, length);
}
```

My question is, is there an underlying reason why we are only given the Substring(startIndex, length) option, and not something akin to Substring(startIndex, endIndex)?

One thing I like about the alternate method is that when picking out pieces of an input line, the last endIndex is the next startIndex, so it is easy to "see" what's going on:

```
var searchString = "ABC";
var a = searchString.SubstringIx(0, 1);
var b = searchString.SubstringIx(1, 2);
var c = searchString.SubstringIx(2, 3);
```

Perhaps a better example of how I think startIndex, endIndex makes it easier to read since I don't think I made that part clear.  Consider these two options:

```
var searchString = GetInputLine();
var a = searchString.SubstringIx(0, 35);
var b = searchString.SubstringIx(35, 60);
var c = searchString.SubstringIx(60, 112);

var d = searchString.Substring(0, 35);
var e = searchString.Substring(35, 25);
var f = searchString.Substring(60, 52);
```

Personally I find the first example easier to read.

Comment: How is that any easier than specifying a length?

Comment: Every time I've gotten a spec sheet for a text file, it has been something like: ID - columns 1-5, Name - columns 6-25, etc...to me it's a lot easier to translate that in my head into name = i.subStringIx(5, 24) than i.subString(5, 19)

Comment: If I had to guess I would say that it's like a legacy thing from the time then people had to implement their own array logic and it's simpler to think in such way if you are dealing with bytes. For example, you would say "take 8 bytes starting from array element 127" and not "give all me bytes between array element 159 and 175". Since string is basically an array it makes sense for it to have this kind of implementation of substring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are exactly two reasonable methods to specify a one-dimensional subset:

1. start and length
2. start and end

There is no reason why one of them should be "better", its mainly a matter of taste.

Comment: This is essentially what I figured.  But I didn't know if there was something else going on down in the framework that forced the C# design team to "pick" one over the other.  In fact, I would suspect that under the hood they add startIndex and length to find the endIndex.

Answer (score 1):

Other languages use this method. Specifically something like:
java.lang.StringBuilder.substring(int start, int end)
From MSDN no less-
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/aa988974%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

This seems like a perfectly reasonable way of accomplishing the same thing.